# JAVA: if/else statements producing incorrect result

Tags: java, if-statement

I am creating a guessing-game program where the user must enter a number between 1 and 100 and try and guess the 'magic number'.

I am trying to add a 'hint' feature where depending on how close the users guess was to the random number chosen by the computer, a message will appear displaying messages such as:

- Freezing—more than 50 away.
- Cold—more than 25 away.
- Cool—more than 15 away.
- Warm—more than 10 away.
- Hot—more than 5 away.
- Boiling—between 1 and 4 away.

Unfortunately when I enter a number and press the button "GUESS", the wrong 'hint' shows up for the number guessed. Specifically, "Boiling! Between 1 and 4 away!"
However, when I enter the exact 'Magic Number', the correct text shows up. ""YOU GOT IT! " (the magic number) " is the magic number!"

In order for me to see what the 'Magic Number' is each time, I have added a line of code that I will remove later.

FYI: This is for a school project, and my teacher added this hint to the assignment:

> In the Math class, there is a method that you can use to find the absolute (positive) value of a number. You will need to use this method to help you determine how far the guess is from the secret number. This will allow you to determine which message you should report for a hint. Sample code below:

```
int numAbsolute = Math.abs(num);
System.out.println(num); // output: -12
System.out.println(numAbsolute); // output: 12
```

> Also, you will need to set up two conditional control structures to produce the two different messages (one from the basic assignment and one for the enrichment). You can join the two messages to form one message using the concatenate operator (+) and display the concatenated message in a text field.

Here is my conditional control structure code:

```
public class GuessingGame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    //Create the random number between 1 & 100
    int randNum = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);
    int numAbsolute = Math.abs(randNum);
```

And the rest of my code:

```
private void guessButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

        System.out.println("Secret number is " + randNum); // to be removed later
        
        int input;
        input = Integer.parseInt (guessInput.getText());
        
        if (input == randNum)
        {
        guessOutput.setText("YOU GOT IT! " + randNum + " is the magic number!");
        }
        else if (input - randNum + numAbsolute > 1)
        {
            guessOutput.setText("Boiling! Between 1 and 4 away!");
        }
        else if (input - randNum + numAbsolute > 5)
        {
            guessOutput.setText("Hot! More than 5 away!");
        }
        else if (input - randNum + numAbsolute > 15)
        {
            guessOutput.setText("Cool: More than 15 away.");
        }    
        else if (input - randNum + numAbsolute > 10)
        {
            guessOutput.setText("Warm! More than 10 away!");
        }
        else if (input - randNum + numAbsolute > 25)
        {
            guessOutput.setText("Cold: More than 25 away.");
        }
        else if (input - randNum + numAbsolute > 50)
        {
            guessOutput.setText("Sheesh, Freezing: more than 50 away.");
        }
        


    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The order of your if statements are backward.  The absolute value difference of almost any guess will be greater than 1.  Also, you should be checking the absolute value of the difference between the guess and the random number.

Comment: The problem here has nothing to do with the if/else statements, it's just bad math. Think about specific test cases: If the `randNum` is `10`, and `input` is `19`, you have `19 - 10 + 10`, which results in `19`.  In other words, `randNum` is completely factored out if it is positive.  Think about where else you might put the `Math.abs()` call...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want - you can change the sequence of if-else execution.

Now you started at

```java
        if (input - randNum + numAbsolute > 1){
            guessOutput.setText("Boiling! Between 1 and 4 away!");
        }
```

and this condition is always true.

As an option, you can start

```java
        if (input - randNum + numAbsolute > 50){
            guessOutput.setText("Sheesh, Freezing: more than 50 away.");
        }else if (input - randNum + numAbsolute > 25){
            guessOutput.setText("Cold: More than 25 away.");
        }
```

and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Because `randNum` is a positive number, `numAbsolute` will be equal to `randNum`.

That of course means that `input - randNum + numAbsolute` will always be equal to `input`. And unless `input` is equal to zero, then it will *always* be larger than `1`. So the first `else if` will always be true, and the rest won't be checked.

I believe that the purpose is to take the difference between the `input` and the `randNum`, and get the absolute value of that:

```
numAbsolute = Math.abs(input - randNum);
```

Then you need to consider the order in which you do the checks. If the absolute difference is larger than `5`, then it's also larger than `1`. So you need to reverse the order you check:

```
if (input == randNum) { ... }
else if (numAbsolute > 50) { ... }
else if (numAbsolute > 25) { ... }
else if (numAbsolute > 15) { ... }
else if (numAbsolute > 10) { ... }
else if (numAbsolute > 5) { ... }
else if (numAbsolute > 1) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made a logical mistake. Let's analyze the following condition:

```
else if (input - randNum + numAbsolute > 1)
{
    guessOutput.setText("Boiling! Between 1 and 4 away!");
}
```

If `input - randNum + numAbsolute = 2`, it will become `true`.

If `input - randNum + numAbsolute = 6`, it will become `true`.

If `input - randNum + numAbsolute = 15`, it will become `true`.

and so on...i.e. it will cover all numbers greater than `1`.

In other words, this condition will not allow the following other conditions to be executed:

```
else if (input - randNum + numAbsolute > 5)
{
    guessOutput.setText("Hot! More than 5 away!");
}
else if (input - randNum + numAbsolute > 15)
{
    guessOutput.setText("Cool: More than 15 away.");
}    
else if (input - randNum + numAbsolute > 10)
{
    guessOutput.setText("Warm! More than 10 away!");
}
else if (input - randNum + numAbsolute > 25)
{
    guessOutput.setText("Cold: More than 25 away.");
}
else if (input - randNum + numAbsolute > 50)
{
    guessOutput.setText("Sheesh, Freezing: more than 50 away.");
}
```

**How to solve it?**

Rearrange your conditions in reverse order i.e.

```
if (input == randNum)
{
    guessOutput.setText("YOU GOT IT! " + randNum + " is the magic number!");
}
else if (input - randNum + numAbsolute > 50)
{
    guessOutput.setText("Sheesh, Freezing: more than 50 away.");
}
else if (input - randNum + numAbsolute > 25)
{
    guessOutput.setText("Cold: More than 25 away.");
}
//...
```